# LibGDX Texture , Ram management

Tags: java, libgdx, textures, ram

I am creating android game using libgdx but when I load 9 images it takes 200mb from ram , but the images are from 10 to 17 kb here is where I create textures from that images

```
public static HashMap<String, Texture> ground = new HashMap<String, Texture>();
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
ground.put("ground" + i,new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("groundImages/ground" + i + ".png")));
}
```

Comment: Please check ths post from our Game Development community from the below link
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48304/which-image-format-is-more-memory-efficient-png-jpeg-or-gif

Comment: How does that compare to uncompressed texture data (PNG supports RLE compression, IIRC)? Are you including generated mipmaps, copies made into system and VRAM? How are you measuring memory use (overall JVM, difference pre- and post-loading, or specifically those objects)?

Comment: I am using PNG 8 with 256 colors  images made with Adobe Illustrator. I am running it on Android device and it takes 70mb from RAM without that images and about 290mb with those images.